# what iPhone application that helps developer most?

Tags: .net, iphone

I just bought an iPhone 3GS and wondering what applications that can help on .NET development.

Comment: Do you mean what application helps the iPhone developer, or what iPhone application helps the developer?

Comment: wait a sec, you can develop .net on an iphone? I thought that was a no no..... you can do web apps though

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't notice the .net tag! Plus (usually) anything that warrants a "subjective" tag should probably be a community wiki. But that in itself is subjective..

Comment: @joshcomley apps that helps developers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I would do is start listening to Podcasts on .Net development and download them on to the iPod in the iPhone, using iTunes

[Here's a link that contains links to such podcasts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490/how-can-i-continue-to-stay-current-on-the-latest-and-maybe-greatest-tools-tech/14573#14573)

If you are specifically looking for apps from appstore, then I don't know, may be search?

And, if you are looking to develop apps for iPhone in .Net, then yeah it's possible using [Mono AOT(Ahead of Time)Compilation](http://www.mono-project.com/AOT) and [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/)

Answer (score 1):

In terms of personal/project planning, I recommend a GTD application.  There are quite a few available, and they vary widely in price.  I use Things, and have for about a month and a half, and its kept me more on-track than any other method I've used before.

If you've never heard of GTD before, check Amazon/Kindle (the Kindle Reader another good app for the iPhone, although the technicial library is lacking at the time being) for "Getting Things Done."

Answer (score 0):

Safari and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com) work for me.

As for a specific application, I don't think there are any.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to running apps written in C# on the iPhone, it's very early days, but efforts are underway thanks to the Mono team:

[Mono/iPhone](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:Iphone)